# trouble connecting to AWS Lightsail via SSH with keys other than default

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, private-key, amazon-lightsail

I have downloaded the default private key and am able to connect via SSH with no problem using that private key. In my Lightsail instance, I went to the SSH Keys tab, created a new key pair and downloaded the new private key (savng it in the correct location on my local machine with proper permissions). However, i am unable to connect using that new private key. Here is the output I get from the command:  `ssh -v  -i ~/.ssh/test.pem me@x.x.x.x`

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Volumes/Norman Data/daveh0/.ssh/config
debug1: /Volumes/Norman Data/daveh0/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/test.pem type -1
debug1: identity file .ssh/test.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to x.x.x.x:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org 
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Bajjqc9SJlMHTB/OrEWKl4ATi6/wI+fB1C351fi5Iwk
debug1: Host 'x.x.x.x' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Volumes/Norman Data/daveh0/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/test.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
me@x.x.x.x : Permission denied (publickey).
```

I've got to be missing a step on the SSH Keys screen, but I can't seem to figure out what it would be. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keypairs are a feature of Linux. The way it works is:

- Somebody tries to connect to the Linux computer using SSH, eg `ssh -i key.pem username@IP-ADDRESS`
- The Linux computer looks in `/home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- If it finds a public key that matches the private key supplied in `key.pem`, then the connection is permitted

Therefore, since you created a new keypair, you will need to **add the new keypair to the appropriate user's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file**.

Your example shows you as logging in as a user called `me`, so the public keypair should be added to `/home/me/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

When first launching a Lightsail or EC2 instance, you can specify a keypair and software on the instance will automatically add the associated public key to the `authorized_keys` file. However, you will need to do this step manually for an already-running instance.

Comment: Wow! I don't know why I didn't just think to add an authorized_keys file for the new user I'm trying to grant access to. That all worked fine - thanks! I guess what I **really** don't understand is how all the uploading and/or adding new keys through the Lightsail console works. I kinda thought they required you to add keys through that GUI (like my managed Wordpress host does), but that's obviously not the case. Problem solved but  still confused.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS Lightsail, I was able to login via SSH by appending my public key id_rsa.pub to remote authorized_keys, I used SFTP (Filezilla) to update authorized_keys file. For SFTP connection I downloaded ssh key from Accounts page.